# Is there a consistent way to link to Google "I Feel Lucky" result?

Tags: html, search

In my application, I'm trying to create a simple way to link to profiles of NFL players on NFL.com based on their name.  Because NFL.com's player profile pages do not have a predictable URL structure, I am trying to create a link to Google's "I Feel Lucky" results based on a URL string:

http://www.google.com/search?q=site:*nfl.com*+*firstname*+*lastname*+*profile*&btnI

The problem is: sometimes the link works and takes me to the first "I Feel Lucky" result, but sometimes it just takes me to the standard Google search results page.

Example 1 (takes me to first result, NFL.com):

http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+Larry+Fitzgerald+profile&btnI

Example 2 (takes me to the Google search results page, not the first result)

http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+Rob+Housler+profile&btnI

Is there a way to ensure I get the "I Feel Lucky" result every time?

**EDIT**

Here are additional examples of links that work and don't work.  Note that the only differences between these links are the search terms yet some transfer you to the first Google result website and some take you to the actual search results.

Work (i.e. we are sent to the site of the first Google Result, NFL.com)

- [http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Jaron+Brown%22+profile&btnI](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com%20%22Jaron%20Brown%22%20profile&btnI)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Dominique+Davis%22+profile&btnI](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com%20%22Dominique%20Davis%22%20profile&btnI)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Drew+Davis%22+profile&btnI](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com%20%22Drew%20Davis%22%20profile&btnI)

Don't Work (i.e. we are sent to Google Search results page)

- [http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22LaRon+Byrd%22+profile&btnI](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com%20%22LaRon%20Byrd%22%20profile&btnI=)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Jared+Crank%22+profile&btnI](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com%20%22Jared%20Crank%22%20profile&btnI)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Early+Doucet%22+profile&btnI](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com%20%22Early%20Doucet%22%20profile&btnI)

Comment: Why not a link to the nfl.comdirectly?

Comment: Using "I'm feeling lucky" links is, well, leaving the website to randomness. The two very links used in the question, in one the first result is a profile (the wanted page, I believe), in other, the result is a page pointing to an event. Is that the intended behavior?

Comment: In my application I sometimes have to update player information in my local database.  The best place to get that information is on each player's profile on NFL.com.  So in my app I want to click a link which will take me straight to **any** player's profile page on NFL.com.  Since player profile page URLs are not predictable, I'm trying to indirectly navigate there through Google's "I Feel Lucky".

Comment: My goal is to bring up the player's profile page on NFL.com **every time**.  But sometimes it works (take me to their profile page) and sometimes it doesn't (takes me to full search results instead).

Comment: To answer acdcjunior's question, the reason is because the URLs of player profiles aren't predictable.  If I had to hard-code each profile link I'd spend all of my time maintaining these links.  The goal is to avoid that and use Google's I Feel Lucky to do the leg work.

Comment: maybe you'll have more luck at this other stack exchange web site: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/ . I don't think your question is off-topic there.

Comment: 1st link doesn't work for me, 2nd and 3rd works.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/url-format-for-googles-im-feeling-lucky

Answer (score 9):

http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI  Replace Stack Oveflow with your words

Comment: Doesn't work for me. http://www.google.com/search?q=knot+sum&btnl

Comment: @isomorphismes That's because it's btn<uppercase i>, not btn<lowercase l>

Comment: @sohail Oh perfect, thank you @sohail!

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I agree with some of the comments regarding I'm feeling lucky being unpredictable, I managed to get those links working by including the players name in quotations. I'm not sure why it didn't work normally though. The following links work:

http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Rob+Housler%22+profile&btnI
http://www.google.com/search?q=site:nfl.com+%22Larry+Fitzgerald%22+profile&btnI

Since I'm not from the US, I don't know any other names off the top of my head to test it with, but those two links work. %22 is quotations, so make sure to leave it around the players name.

Comment: This does seem to help a bit, although it's still about 50-50.  In a field of 40 players I was able to successfully get the first result in 18 instances, versus 16 without using quotes.  What is really odd is that Google I Feel Lucky ALWAYS works, but linking to it only works some of the time.  Any other ideas for improving success rates are welcome.

Comment: Can you post a few samples of what does work and what doesn't? It'll give a bit more test material.

Comment: Added more examples to original post as requested.

Comment: See more examples at http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10699/url-format-for-googles-im-feeling-lucky