# Automatically Click Search Results

Tags: javascript, jquery, onload, prompt, onload-event

This may be a very rookie error I am making, but my situation is this. I have successfully made a script that when entered into a Google Chrome bookmark, it will bring up a prompt box upon the user clicking on the bookmark. From there, after they hit enter, it brings said user to a list of search results. What I want to do is put another piece of code in this same bookmark so that it automatically clicks on the first result on the search results page after it loads. Any ideas?

```
javascript: (function MCC() {
var feature = prompt('What is your search query?', '');
if (feature != null) {
    window.open('https://www.google.com/#q=' + encodeURIComponent(feature));
    window.onload = function MyClient() {
        document.getElementById('mHSB').click();
    }
}})();
```

Comment: you could use jquery's `ready`. `$(function() { ... } );` your inner html line makes no sense.

Comment: `javascript: (onload` <--- where dd you learn that syntax? yikes. And `document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = window.open('https://abc.com/' + encodeURIComponent(feature));
    ` makes no sense

Comment: Oops, I forgot to take that out! My bad. I am in all honesty not very familiar with jquery's `ready`. I will update the op and remove the innerHTML as it functions the same either way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a way to interact with a page inside of another window/frame. Your code snippet would run the function in the *current* window when the new window loaded.

If you are searching with google you could change the URL, something like

> http://www.google.com/search?q=searchTerm&btnI

This should be the same as entering the search term and clicking Im feelin lucky (which should load the first result)

I got that link from

[Is there a consistent way to link to Google "I Feel Lucky" result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950941/is-there-a-consistent-way-to-link-to-google-i-feel-lucky-result)

If you are searching on your own site/ a site where you can add code maybe a query-string switch would be a good idea.